# Difference between FRP and FP + lazy-evaluation

Tags: frp

I just stumbled upon the term [functional reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) on wikiedia. Altough I think the aforementioned article does not thoroughly explain the term, I ended up with some sort of a (possibly completely wrong) 'concept' of FRP:

1. (some) values can change over time
2. Events have to be handled
3. ...maybe more?

so, given my simplistic model of FRP, I propose that a simple, lazily evaluated functional language naturally meets the criteria.

1. We don't distinguish between 'changing' values (like 'signals' or something) and 'normal' immutable values. They are declared (and treated) in exactly the same way.

   ```
   someNumber = 10
   somFun a b = a + b * 3
   mouseX = fst MousePosition
   ```

thanks to lazy evaluation, in every call the 'current' value of all involved terms is used, e.g.:
Say, if `someFun someNumber mouseX` is called, the current value of `mouseX` is plugged in.

2. Events are just function calls.

Comment: "*They are declared (and treated) in exactly the same way*" - well, there's your problem. They are not the same thing, and you're messing with semantics very hard here. How would you try to express things like "the latest occurence of one of these events" or "the average of this signal over the last 10 seconds"?

Comment: Can you expand on "*Events are just function calls.*", please? I have no idea what you mean by that. What's a function call in a lazily evaluated language anyway?

Comment: "_They are not the same thing, and you're messing with semantics very hard here_" - imho I am just suggesting a very simple (probably simplistic) semantics... all values can change, some just happen not to.. kind of like viewing constants just as 0-ary functions.
"_How would you try to express [...] "the average of this signal over the last 10 seconds"_" - Not possible, in fact I didn't assume that accessing "historical" data is crucial to the FRP concept.

Comment: "_What's a function call in a lazily evaluated language anyway?_" the same as in a strictly evaluated language... an evaluation just done with a different srategy..
In this simple model that basically means that 'main' is being called perpetually while at the same time a user interacts with the system by changing those values he is given access to. The result/output of 'main' ist perpetually 'rendered' in some sense (e.g. in a browser)..

Comment: Sounds like you're talking of [incremental computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_computing) or [dataflow programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming), like in a spreadsheet processor. But FRP is indeed more than that, it's explicit about changes.